# Search text field on menu bar

Tags: eclipse-rcp

In a Eclipse RCP application, is there any way I can have text field (for search) on menu bar?
For example I have menu:

```
File Edit ...                                          Search: |___text field___|
```

The text field is located at the right end of the menu bar.

Comment: In latest eclipse version **Quick access** text box will do this but its on toolbar. Press `Ctrl + 3`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is easily possible. But you could use the [CoolBar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CoolBarExamples.htm) to create this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can place an SWT control on the toolbar, but it doesn't work for menus. Here is the toolbar way:

1. Open the extensions tab in plugin.xml file
2. Add a menuContribution extension to org.eclipse.ui.menus and set it as a toolbar (toolbar:ID)
3. Add a toolbar to this menuContribution
4. Add a control to this toolbar
5. Double click and create the class which extends WorkbenchWindowControlContribution and fill the createControl(...) function using the desired SWT controls.

After setting the menuContribution as a menu, it is still possible to add a control, but unfortunately, it does not show any controls.